# Ajax call fails with HTTP status 0 when using Cordova WKWebView plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview

I've been trying to update my Cordova iOS app to use the new WKWebView pluggable web view, but I have run into an issue where I cannot make ajax calls when it is installed.  When I try to make the following call, I get a an error result of HTTP status 0:

```
return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
        url: 'https://mytestserver.com/settings',
        timeout: 10000 
    }))
```

I am using Cordova 5.4.1 with iOS platform 4.0.0 and my test device is running iOS 9.2.  This code works as expected as soon as I remove the WKWebView plugin and Cordova reverts to UIWebView.  I have tried with and without the whitelist plugin (1.2.0).

My config.xml includes:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

My index.html CSP tag is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src *; connect-src https: blob: 'self'; object-src 'self' blob:;">
```

Comment: Have you applied Apple's `ATS`? Is your Javascript in the index.html page? Or is ALL your Javascript in it's own file? Is this strictly an `iOS` issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read the `Limitations` section of the doc?

If you are upgrading from UIWebView, please note the limitations of using WKWebView as outlined in [our issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10146?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20wkwebview-known-issues).

I think your problem is that [WKWebView is affected by CORS](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10144)

So you have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the server

[Examples](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: This turned out to be my issue, after a fashion.  I did indeed have CORS headers set up on my server, but in two places, so the server was sending *two*  Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, which is a violation of the spec.

Comment: Confirmed this is the solution for Telerik WKWebView 0.6.9 and Cordova 4.0.0 (iOS 3.8.0) running on iOS 9.3.2

Comment: How and where do I add this on my server?

Comment: The Examples link (http://enable-cors.org/server.html) explains how based on the server you are using, there are plenty of them, it's different for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html the ajax work correctly but in anothers html files didn't, so i had to use index like master page for another files modifying the app and the app work.